# Run Javascript code on Page Load

Tags: javascript, .net

I am using the jquery tool bootstrap wizard and there is a function within it to start the wizard that I want to load up automatically when I go to a page.

Here is my code:

```
$('#open-wizard').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        wizard.show();
                    });
```

I need to have this code run whenever I load the page. I know for functions you could just add, not sure how I do this with my code, I tried to put it in a function and didn't work.

```
window.onload = load();

function load() {
//javascript function here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is $(document).ready();

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    wizard.show();
                 });
```

Answer (score 1):

when using `window.onload` you do not need the perenthesis. change `load()` to `load`..

```
function load() {
//javascript function here
}
window.onload = load;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,and i suggest u put the js import tags at the bottom of the page file.
eg:

```
 <scrpit ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**document.ready (jQuery)**

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
    // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
    alert("(document).ready was called - document is ready!");  
 });
```

*document.ready will execute right after the HTML document is loaded property, and the DOM is ready*

**window.load (Built-in JavaScript)**

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
   // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
   alert("(window).load was called - window is loaded!");
});
```

*The window.load however will wait for the page to be fully loaded, this includes inner frames, images etc.*